# Typescript: Starting a reduce statement with an initial value?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a fairly complex reduce statement where I turn an array and also an array of arrays into an array of objects. Here's my starting arrays and the type I would like to end up with:

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'pear', 'plum', 'grape'];
const fruitConsumers = [
  ['Jeremy, Claude', '', '', 'Helen, Benny, Sophie', ''],
  ['', 'Francis, Paul', '', 'Alice', 'Bob, Tracy', 'Lacey, Stacey'],
];

type FruitPersonMap = {
  apple: string[],
  banana: string[],
  pear: string[],
  plum: string[],
  grape: string[],
  people?: {
    name: string,
    fruit: string,
  }[]
}
```

For the most part this works pretty well, except for the part where I'd like to have an array of all the people and their fruits at the end. For some reason, typescript doesn't like that. Here is my function:

```js
const makeFruitPersonMap = (fruits: string[], consumers: string[][]): FruitPersonMap[] => {
  return consumers.map(consumerSet => {
    return consumerSet.reduce((acc, val: string, i: number) => {
      // the nth item in a consumer list will always correspond to the nth fruit
      const currentFruit = fruits[i];
      // turn the people into an array instead of a comma separated string
      const peopleList = val.split(',').map(name => name.trim());
      // turn the array of people into an array of objects with keys name, fruit
      const peopleWithFruit = peopleList.map(person => ({
        name: person,
        fruit: currentFruit,
      }))
      // add the current key to the accumulator and add the people objects onto the list.
      return {
        ...acc,
        [currentFruit]: peopleList,
        people: peopleWithFruit ? acc.people.concat(peopleWithFruit) : acc.people
      }
    }, { people: [] }) as FruitPersonMap
  })
};
```

Doing this gives me an error: `Conversion of type '{ people: never[]; }' to type 'FruitPersonMap' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first`

What I don't understand is why the `people` key is given type `never[]`. Concatting things into the `people` array also gives me this problem, which is odd to me. I have also tried adding the `people` key within the callback function (`if (!acc.people) acc.people = []`) but then I get an error about `acc.people` not existing on `{}`. I mean, I agree that it's a bad way to set the value of the `people` key, but I've checked on whether or not it exists. What is the deal!

So I guess my question is twofold. Why is Typescript unhappy about this particular way of handling reduce, and is there a way to set up a reduce's initial value that doesn't result in this problem?

Answer (score -1):

I figured this out about 30 seconds after typing all of the question up.

New type:

```js
type PeopleList = {
  people: {
    name: string,
    fruit: string,
  }[]
}
```

Updated function:

```js
const testFunc = (fruits: string[], consumers: string[][]) => {
  return consumers.map(consumerSet => {
    return consumerSet.reduce((acc, val: string, i: number) => {
      const currentFruit = fruits[i];
      const peopleList = val.split(',').map(name => name.trim());
      const peopleWithFruit = peopleList.map(person => ({
        name: person,
        fruit: currentFruit,
      }))
      return {
        ...acc,
        [currentFruit]: peopleList,
        people: peopleWithFruit ? acc.people.concat(peopleWithFruit) : acc.people
      }
    }, { people: [] } as PeopleList) as FruitPersonMap
  })
};
```

Note `{ people: [] } as PeopleList`: setting a type to the initial value that overlaps with FruitPersonMap fixes it.

Thought I would leave the question up in case anyone else comes across this issue and gets confused, like I did.